# remove blank space between footnote mark and bibliographic reference

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, indentation, footcite

I am running into issues with the layout of the footnotes in my document. I’m using texlive 2021, Lualatex and Biblatex/Biber, and for reasons have to include my references in the footnotes. However, the indent just makes it look horrible and untidy, and I have no clue how to fix it. I’ve tried [hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}, also \deffootnote, and a few other solutions I can’t remember any longer, but nothing works.

What it looks like:

[image: lots of blank space between footnote mark and reference]

I want the reference in the footnotes to be flush with the footnote mark so it looks more tidy and hopefully takes up less space. In other words, how do I make the big white space between the footnote mark and the reference disappear?

MWE and bibliography here, but since this is the first time I’ve made one, please let me know if something is missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[rmargin=15mm,lmargin=15mm,tmargin=15mm,bmargin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,autocite=footnote,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,maxcitenames=1,firstinits=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "normal" citation commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography

\usepackage{hyperref}

\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
  \textsuperscript{\makebox[1em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{
\clearlist{language}
\clearlist{address}
\clearlist{publisher}
%\clearfield{date}
\clearfield{issn}
\clearlist{location}
\clearfield{note}
\clearfield{related}
\clearfield{series}
\clearfield{number}
\clearname{translator}
}

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{pagetotal}}{}}

\begin{document}


Bla bla\autocites{bryggennames1981johnsen}{namenwelten2004}, also bla bla\footcite{spurkland2004}.
Further blablabla\autocites{fannekbein2020zilmer}{bergensticks2020zilmer2}, as also blablabla\footcite{runeseditors2010barnes}.


\end{document}
```

Bibliography

```
@InProceedings{bryggennames1981johnsen,
  author     = {Johnsen, Ingrid Sanness},
  booktitle  = {Proceedings of the First International Symposium on Runes and Runic Inscriptions},
  title      = {Personal Names in Inscriptions from Towns of Medieval Norway},
  editor     = {Thompson, Claiborne W.},
  number     = {VII},
  pages      = {119-128},
  series     = {Michigan Germanic Studies},
  year       = {1981},
}

@Book{namenwelten2004,
  title      = {Namenwelten: Orts- und Personennamen in historischer Sicht},
  editor     = {van Nahl, Astrid and Elmevik, Lennart and Brink, Stefan},
  isbn       = {3110181088},
  language   = {ger},
  number     = {44},
  publisher  = {Walter de Gruyter},
  series     = {Ergänzungsbände zum Reallexikon der germanischen Altertumskunde},
  address    = {Berlin},
   year       = {2004},
}

@InCollection{spurkland2004,
  author    = {Terje Spurkland},
  booktitle = {Scandinavia and Europe 800-1350. Contact, Conflict, and Coexistence},
  publisher = {Brepols},
  title     = {Literacy and 'Runacy' in Medieval Scandinavia},
  year      = {2004},
  editor    = {John Adams and Cathy Holman},
  pages     = {333-344},
  doi       = {ISBN 2-503-51085-X},
}

@Unpublished{fannekbein2020zilmer,
  author    = {Zilmer, Kristel},
  title     = {“Fann ek bein..., I found a bone…”: Runic Artefacts as Material Evidence of Writing in Medieval Norwegian Towns},
}

@Article{bergensticks2020zilmer2,
  author    = {Zilmer, Kristel},
  journal   = {Maal og Minne},
  title     = {Survey of medieval inscribed objects from Bergen: Items other than wooden sticks or pieces of wood},
  year      = {2020},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1-15},
}

@Article{runeseditors2010barnes,
  author       = {Barnes, Michael},
  date         = {2010},
  journaltitle = {Futhark: International Journal of Runic Studies},
  title        = {Runes and Editors: The Changing Face of Corpus Editions},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {7-26},
  url          = {https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?dswid=-1914&pid=diva2:381131&c=1&searchType=SIMPLE&language=en&query=&af=[]&aq=[[{"issn":"1892-0950"},{"volume":"1"}]]&aq2=[[]]&aqe=[]&noOfRows=100&sortOrder=page&sortOrder2=title_sort_asc&onlyFullText=false&sf=all},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many situations you need to "comment out" line ends if you don't want spurious spaces. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).

Basically every line in your `\AtEveryCitekey{` needs an `%` at the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[rmargin=15mm,lmargin=15mm,tmargin=15mm,bmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-inote,
  maxcitenames=1,giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\deffootnote[1em]{1em}{1em}{%
  \textsuperscript{\makebox[1em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}}


\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearlist{language}%
  \clearlist{address}%
  \clearlist{publisher}%
  %\clearfield{date}%
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearlist{location}%
  \clearfield{note}%
  \clearfield{related}%
  \clearfield{series}%
  \clearfield{number}%
  \clearname{translator}%
  \clearfield{pagetotal}%
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{bryggennames1981johnsen,
  author     = {Johnsen, Ingrid Sanness},
  booktitle  = {Proceedings of the First International Symposium on Runes and Runic Inscriptions},
  title      = {Personal Names in Inscriptions from Towns of Medieval Norway},
  editor     = {Thompson, Claiborne W.},
  number     = {VII},
  pages      = {119-128},
  series     = {Michigan Germanic Studies},
  year       = {1981},
}

@Book{namenwelten2004,
  title      = {Namenwelten: Orts- und Personennamen in historischer Sicht},
  editor     = {van Nahl, Astrid and Elmevik, Lennart and Brink, Stefan},
  isbn       = {3110181088},
  language   = {ger},
  number     = {44},
  publisher  = {Walter de Gruyter},
  series     = {Ergänzungsbände zum Reallexikon der germanischen Altertumskunde},
  address    = {Berlin},
   year       = {2004},
}

@InCollection{spurkland2004,
  author    = {Terje Spurkland},
  booktitle = {Scandinavia and Europe 800-1350. Contact, Conflict, and Coexistence},
  publisher = {Brepols},
  title     = {Literacy and 'Runacy' in Medieval Scandinavia},
  year      = {2004},
  editor    = {John Adams and Cathy Holman},
  pages     = {333-344},
  doi       = {ISBN 2-503-51085-X},
}

@Unpublished{fannekbein2020zilmer,
  author    = {Zilmer, Kristel},
  title     = {“Fann ek bein..., I found a bone…”: Runic Artefacts as Material Evidence of Writing in Medieval Norwegian Towns},
}

@Article{bergensticks2020zilmer2,
  author    = {Zilmer, Kristel},
  journal   = {Maal og Minne},
  title     = {Survey of medieval inscribed objects from Bergen: Items other than wooden sticks or pieces of wood},
  year      = {2020},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1-15},
}

@Article{runeseditors2010barnes,
  author       = {Barnes, Michael},
  date         = {2010},
  journaltitle = {Futhark: International Journal of Runic Studies},
  title        = {Runes and Editors: The Changing Face of Corpus Editions},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {7-26},
  url          = {https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?dswid=-1914&pid=diva2:381131&c=1&searchType=SIMPLE&language=en&query=&af=[]&aq=[[{"issn":"1892-0950"},{"volume":"1"}]]&aq2=[[]]&aqe=[]&noOfRows=100&sortOrder=page&sortOrder2=title_sort_asc&onlyFullText=false&sf=all},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bla bla\autocites{bryggennames1981johnsen}{namenwelten2004},
also bla bla\footcite{spurkland2004}.
Further blablabla\autocites{fannekbein2020zilmer}{bergensticks2020zilmer2},
as also blablabla\footcite{runeseditors2010barnes}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes without excess space.]